# Pass data through unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have been looking all over for an answer for this...I do not know how to pass data through an unwind segue. I know I am supposed to use `prepareForSegue` but I am not sure what I am supposed to put in. I am trying to pass a variable (myLabel) from a UIPickerView in one class:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    myLabel.text = pickerData[row]
}
```

to another class. I have the unwind segue code already but do not know where to put the prepareForSegue and what to put in it.

Let me know if my question needs more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should do something like this:

```
class MyPickerController : UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

  var pickerData:[String]

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    myLabel.text = pickerData[row]
    performSegueWithIdentifier( "mySegueName", sender: self )
  }

  func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let myController = segue.destinationController as? MyDestinationViewController {
      myController.text = myLabel.text
  }
}
```

That will pass the label text to the MyDestinationViewController instance.
Note that I don't pass the UILabel object, but the text.
You can not place that UILabel object in the destination controller interface, but you can use the text an set another label with it, for example.

Comment: I had to add a NSString variable to MyDestinationViewController but other than that your solution worked, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. It's recommended to use String instead of NSString.

Answer (score 1):

`prepareForSegue` is called in the class of the view controller that you will be unwinding *from* (the view controller that was previously pushed or presented, and is now being popped or dismissed). The destination view controller of the segue is the view controller that will appear as a result.